# Lebesgue Outer measure on open set containing $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $m^*$ denote Lebesgue outer measure. Can one have an open set $G$ containing the rationals in $[0,1]$? with $m^*(G) < 1/2$?

It seems that one can't have this since, if $G$ is open and contains the rationals in $[0,1]$ then $G$ also contains all of $[0,1]$ (you can place an interval around each rational, the interval sits in $G$, and this set of interval covers $[0,1]$).

I am asking because question 37 on page 277 of Carothers' *Real Analysis* begins by saying "Let $G$ be an open set containing the rationals in $[0,1]$ with $m^*(G) < 1/2$.

Thanks.

Comment: Enumerate the rationals $r_1, r_2,\ldots$, and place the $n$'th one in the center of an interval of length $1/2^{n+2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the outer measure of any countable set?  What is the outer measure of $m^*(\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1])$?  What does the definition of outer measure tell you about this set?

Note: it is **not** the case that if $G$ is open and contains the rationals in $[0,1]$, then $G$ also contains all of $[0,1]$.  Just because $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] \subset G$, doesn't mean $\overline{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} \subset G$